# Why is there a delay in 2D when using sockets in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, sockets

I created 2D and 3D projects respectively in Unity environment of the same version.

Every time a client clicks, a text is sent and the server receives it.

The server and client code used in 3D and 2D were written identically.

In 3D, each click on the client screen sends text to the server.

However, whereas in 2D, the result is a little strange.

In 2D, you have to click on the server screen and click on the client screen to see the text being sent.
Also, if the server screen is clicked several times and the client screen is clicked, the text as much as the server screen is clicked is bundled and sent to the server.

The picture below is the result.

[image]

The code used in both projects is as follows.

server code.

```
public class testServer : MonoBehaviour{
    Socket socket = null;
    Socket clientSocket = null;
    ArrayList Connections = new ArrayList();

    public const int PortNumb = 12345;
    byte[] buff = new byte[512];

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start(){
        Debug.Log("Server Start");
        this.socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, PortNumb);
        socket.Bind(ep);
        socket.Listen(100);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update(){
        ArrayList listenList = new ArrayList();
        listenList.Add(socket);
        Socket.Select(listenList, null, null, 1000);

        for (int i = 0; i < listenList.Count; i++){
            clientSocket = ((Socket)listenList[i]).Accept();
            this.Connections.Add(clientSocket);
            Debug.Log("New Client Connected");
        }

        if (Connections.Count != 0){
            ArrayList cloneConnections = new ArrayList(this.Connections);
            Socket.Select(cloneConnections, null, null, 1000);
        
            foreach (Socket client in cloneConnections){
                //int n = clientSocket.Receive(buff);
                int n = client.Receive(buff);
                string data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buff, 0, n);
                
                Debug.Log("data: " + data);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

client code.

```
public class testClient : MonoBehaviour{
    Socket socket = null;
    string cmd = "abcd";

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start(){
        this.socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        var ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 12345);

        try{
            Debug.Log("Connecting to Server");
            socket.Connect(ep);
        }
        catch (SocketException e){
            Debug.Log("Connection Failed:" + e.Message);
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update(){
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) == true){
            byte[] buff = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(cmd);
            socket.Send(buff, SocketFlags.None);
        }
    }
}
```

Why does this happen?